# What was the first story to offer a spaceship landing on an oceangoing vessel?

Tags: history-of, spaceship

Tall ships (in this case tall rocket ships) in science fiction of yesteryear had traditionally turned around and landed on the tips of their oversized fins.

In most of the images I recall from childhood, the rockets landed on alien planets and astronauts would extend a ladder and descend to the surface.

But the surfaces of some planets (including our own) are covered with mostly liquid.

**Question:** I'd like to know the first story to offer a spaceship landing on an oceangoing vessel, rather than on land.

Comment: @Valorum I have just asked for one! "...has in fact happened in **a** science fiction story" makes that clear,  I still don't see any problem with this question.

Comment: @Valorum as much as I thoroughly **hate** this policy, meta consensus is that ["is there any" questions are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/98028). So voting to leave open, but to be frank, also downvoting because these "is there any" questions are rarely interesting. (uhoh, I don't mean that to be rude, but I wanted the distinction between my Leave Open vote and downvote to be made clear)

Comment: [Is this an unpopular type of question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12918/51174)

Comment: If I was going to DV this, it'd be because I just can't watch another video narrated by Scott. The 'popularity' off a Q is self-evident in its votes. What is (which this is) and what isn't ontopic has been discussed to death for the last 10y.

Comment: OK, so back to the question.  This definitely happens in _[Consider Phlebas](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8935689-consider-phlebas)_ but I'd be surprised to find it was actually the first.

Comment: @Spencer one way to find out will be to post an answer with a short passage quoted describing the event, and mention the first time the story was published. I'll leave a comment of thanks won't accept. This will put the question back in the active queue and bring it to the attention of others and if an earlier occurrence is known it will be added as an answer. Ideally (to me) I would have left my question worded as "...has in fact happened in a science fiction story?" but the "first occurrence" style seems to be what the community settled on over the years. (See linked meta question) *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh Fun fact added to my answer.

Comment: @Spencer indeed! I'm off to the used book store this weekend then...

Comment: FWIW, the torchships in Heinlein's [Time for the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_the_Stars) (1956) are globe shaped, and cannot stand on solid ground, they're designed to land in water, although they can also cope with liquid ammonia.

Comment: @PM2Ring [torchship sighting](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23092/12102)! I wonder if the word *torchship* was coined by Heinlein and if that would be worth asking as a new question

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchship) seems to think so. And I can't recall any earlier uses of the term, but my memory isn't quite as good as it was when I started reading scifi 50-odd years ago. ;)

Comment: @uhoh That's question material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iain M. Banks's 1987 novel *[Consider Phlebas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consider_Phlebas)* (the first Culture novel)  features a spaceship landing on a huge oceangoing liner in an even huger artificial ocean, on a mind-bogglingly enormous Culture Orbital.

*Consider Phlebas* is set during the Culture-Idiran War.  The Culture decides to strategically withdraw from a volume of space, to do this they decide to evacuate and demolish an Orbital with  billions of inhabitants. *(Vogon Prostetnic Jeltz, eat your h...oh wait)*.

One of the attractions on this particular Orbital, Vavatch, are huge ocean-going vessels, called "Megaships" that sail around the Orbital-girdling ocean. But now they're CAM fodder.

The main character, a Changer named Bora Horza Gobuchul, is an agent of the Idirans. He was rescued after a space battle by some scavengers who wanted his spacesuit. He had to fight and kill one of the scavengers to earn a place on the crew.

Horza's been ordered to capture the story's McGuffin, a lost Culture Mind, and so he plots to kill the scavengers' captain Kraiklyn and take his place.

Horza sees his chance when Kraiklyn decides to loot one of the empty Megaships before the whole thing is demolished.

That's tame compared to what happens after the scavengers' ship lands on the Megaship.....

**This just in**: Since your question was inspired by the  SpaceX floating autonomous landing platforms, just be aware that SpaceX founder [Elon Musk actually chose the names](https://www.space.com/28445-spacex-elon-musk-drone-ships-names.html) *Just Read the Instructions* and *Of Course I Still Love You* as an homage to Iain M. Banks's Culture novels.  The Minds controlling Culture ships and other structures choose [names like these](https://theculture.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_spacecraft_in_the_Culture_series) for themselves, and it's one of the more entertaining details of the whole Culture millieu.

Comment: As I said in my comment, I doubt it's the earliest, but it's the only answer I have so far.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This sounds fun; I'll try to get my hands on a copy soon.