# What was the first movie with an object associated with a person being depicted to fall more slowly on Mars than it would on Earth?

Tags: movie, history-of

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44847/would-a-flag-planted-by-astronauts-on-mars-need-an-upper-horizontal-pole-like-th?noredirect=1#comment145193_44847) in Space SE got me wondering, and I can't think of a counterexample.

> Especially since Hollywood seems to think that Mars has 1g (and all other planets too). :-)

When an object is dropped from height `h`, the time it takes to fall is `t = sqrt(2h/g)`. Values for `g` on Earth, Mars and the Moon are about 9.81 and 3.72 m/s<sup>2</sup> so dropping something from 1 meter takes 0.45, 0.71 and 1.11 seconds, respectively.

We have real video of objects dropped on the Moon from 1971 shown below, but my question is about *Science Fiction movies that take place on Mars*. What was the first movie with an object associated with a person being depicted to fall more slowly on Mars than it would on Earth?

"Associated with a person" means somehow in proximity to a being, perhaps dropped by them, as opposed to pure CGI explosions or things otherwise falling out of the sky.

---

Hammer vs Feather - Physics on the Moon Apollo 15 (cued at `00:54`)

> Courtesy: NASA - Galileo and Apollo 15. At the end of the last Apollo 15 moon walk, Commander David Scott (pictured above) performed a live demonstration for the television cameras. He held out a geologic hammer and a feather and dropped them at the same time.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should ask this here or in Movies SE; it seems at least marginally on-topic in both but it's more likely someone here will remember something.

Comment: I've changed this to [[tag:history-of]] and a first of question because the previous wording was borderline off topic just falling into the off topic side in my opinion.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thanks! Folks I can delete here and post in Movies SE if it's off-topic here, just let me know what you think.

Comment: Asking about the first occurrence of something appearing in the sci-fi genre is perfectly on topic and fine here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot [oh that's right!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/227613/51174) +18/-14

Comment: You're specifically interested in something being dropped on Mars, not on "any planet other than Earth"?

Comment: Now I'm wondering - are that hammer and feather still there?  We never see him pick them up again, and I'm not even sure how easy it is to bend over and pick stuff up off the ground in those suits.  Might be a good SX.SE question...

Comment: I'm not an expert on recent movies and television shows set on Mars, so I can only wonder whether the answer to what movie first showed objects falling slowly on Mars might turn out to be some movie made in the year 2030!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot While it's for some reason (entertainment?) not technically off-topic. Such questions are notoriously problematic. And this question doesn't have much entertainment value, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Steve-O I was particularly interested in Mars, but Mercury also has a rocky surface that one could stand on and a similar gravity to Mars, and there are plenty of rocky moons in the solar system as well. If there's a compelling answer for another body, perhaps even a "[Texas-sized asteroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_(1998_film))" I could modify the question to accommodate.

Comment: @Mithoron I didn't realize that the entertainment value of a question was important. While I'm a horribly boring person, I've tried to take it under consideration for this next question; how did I do? [Why did the  Armageddon (1998) plot require a "rogue comet that jarred loose a Texas-sized asteroid"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232952/51174)

Comment: @uhoh While entertainment shouldn't be important, it is one of main ingredients for HNQ. I'm afraid this Armageddon question didn't do it - not enough clarity/brevity... and fun. Pointing out how improbable is such event would maybe help a bit.

Comment: @Steve-O [Which planets and moons can you walk on?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15062/12102)

Comment: If you weren't specifying a movie, I'd consider answering with "[A Martian Odyssey](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/23731/23731-h/23731-h.htm)" by Stanley G. Weinbaum.

Comment: "Values for g on Earth, Mars and the Moon are about 9.81 and 3.72 m/s² so..." You left off the Moon value, 1.625 m/s².